# What is the default state of execution of layers and models in tensorflow 2.0, eager mode or graph mode?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In keras tensorflow, if I do not explicitly mention what to use (eager mode or graph mode), in which mode will the model(defined as a subclass of tf.keras.models.model) run? And similarly, what about a layer (defined as a subclass of tf.keras.layers.Layer)?
I could not find any concrete information about this anywhere.

This link: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules
says that : "You can define a graph in the model above by adding the @tf.function decorator to indicate that this code should run as a graph."
So does that mean: unless I use @tf.function decorator on the call function on a model, it will run in eager mode by default? And is this the case for layers inheriting from tf.keras.layers.Layer as well?

Also, what if I use the @tf.function decorator on the call function of a layer but do not use it on the model (of which the layer is a part of)? Will only that 1 layer run in graph mode while the rest of the model runs in eager mode?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The default in graph_mode. @tf.function is used when you define custom layers or sub-class models.

Answer (score 0):

This question send me down a little rabbit hole, so I'll share what I found.

Default in TF 2 is graph mode for a model. If you create a model you can check the `run_eagerly` attribute of it. For a standard `Sequential` model it is False, indicating that it'll run in graph mode if possible.
You can also check if *the current thread* has eager execution enabled with `tf.executing_eagerly()`. It will give you `True` in the main thread, which does not mean that the whole TF is running eagerly now. It is explained in detail [its docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/executing_eagerly). For example, it will be `False` inside a function decorated with the `@tf.function` decorator.

In this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs#taking_advantage_of_graphs) is also an important sentence:

> tf.function applies to a function and all other functions it calls

You can test this with the following small code snippet

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x):
        print('layer test')
        return x

class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
        self.l2 = CustomLayer()

    def call(self, x):
        print('model test')
        x = self.l(x)
        return self.l2(x)

print('Executing eagerly now: ' + str(tf.executing_eagerly()))
model = CustomModel()
x = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([3, 3]), (1, -1))

print('Beginning')
for i in range(5):
    model(x)
print('After normal calls')

@tf.function
def train_step(x):
    print('Executing eagerly now: ' + str(tf.executing_eagerly()))
    print('train step')
    model(x)

for i in range(5):
    train_step(x)
print('After train loop')
```

This creates a custom layer with decorator and a small custom model. The model call method is called 5 times in a normal loop, and 5 times in a `train_step` with decorator. Note the print statements. You'd expect 5 prints of 'model test' per loop, and 5x 'train step' for the second loop. The output is:

> Executing eagerly now: True
> Beginning
> model test
> layer test
> model test
> model test
> model test
> model test
> After normal calls
> Executing eagerly now: False
> train step
> model test
> After train loop

If a function gets traced as a graph, `print` statements gets only executed one time, the time the function gets traced. After that, TF will use the constructed graph, which will only have TF functions and no more print statements. It is explained later on in [this section](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs#using_tffunction) in detail.
You can see for the first loop, that the `CustomLayer` is being traced (only one 'layer test' print), but the model itself executes in non-graph mode (multiple 'model test' prints).
When wrapping the training step in a `tf.function` decorator, the model itself gets traced too (notice only one 'train step', 'model test' and 'executing..' print), while the layer itself is already traced and is not retraced.
You could add a `@tf.function` decorator to the `.call()` method of the `CustomModel` to enable graph mode from the beginning for this model.

I suppose it is best practice to just wrap the `training_step` in the decorator, and not mix graph and eager mode to fully use the speed benefits of graph mode.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "Default in TF 2 is graph mode for a mode" and then your code snippet shows the default is actually eager mode (which it is). Graph mode is only default when using functions such as `fit`, and `run_eagerly` argument only exists when using `model.compile`, not when creating the model object itself.

Comment: Let me rephrase it, graph mode is default for every model/layer that TF provides you, like `Sequential` model or `Dense` layer. If you write your own layer and use it in a `Sequential` model, it will most likely be in graph mode. If you code your own training loop from scratch, you have to provide the decorator to enable graph mode. Most people use just the tools/models provided by TF, and by that they use graph mode.

Comment: And with`run_eagerly`, I meant the **attribute** of the model (a property variable of an existing model, saving a characteristic), not a parameter/argument of a method like `.compile()`.